# Inserting data into the VIEW , result in data being inserted into the original table, why is this happening?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, query, view, plsql

I have a table as you can see below:

```
create table table_test
(col_id   number(1))
```

The table has below data:

```
col_id
------
  1
  2
  3
```

I create a view based on this table:

```
create view v_table_test as
select *
from table_test;
```

And then I run this query that inserts one row in the `VIEW`:

```
insert into v_table_test 
values(1);

  commit;
```

And then I have this data in my table:

```
col_id
------
  1
  2
  3
  1
```

I haven't seen or even heard this before (neither my colleagues!) that if we insert data in `VIEW` ,the value is being inserted into the original table !! I want to know why on earth does this happen and why DBMS does not prevent this from happening?? I expect that the DBMS would definitely prevent this! Can anybody explain this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-view/oracle-updatable-view/) and do a bit more reading. Basically some views are updateable depending on the columns they may or may not have and whether they're PK-s, FK-s or other constaints.

Comment: Also, your insert - as shown - is into the _table_ (`insert into table_test`), not the view (`v_table_test`).

Comment: @pmdba Thanks , I've just edited my query.

Comment: A view is nothing but a stored, pre-defined SELECT statement.  It has no storage of its own.  Inserting or updating data "in a view" is - _by definition_ - updating the underlying tables.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the view to be read-only, you can use the `with read only` option:

```
create or replace view v_table_test as
select *
from table_test
with read only;
```

```
insert into v_table_test values(1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-42399: cannot perform a DML operation on a read-only view
```

Otherwise, why shouldn't you be able to perform any DML you want on a view? That also goes for inline views, e.g.

```
insert into (select col_id from table_test) values (1)
```

```
update (select col_id from table_test) set col_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a correct behavior, when you create a view that references one table, and the structure of the view holds every single field of the table that is constrained for the insert statement, then an insert operation can work, and is intended to happen, since the view becomes a maintenance view, imagine that instead of giving the entire definition of a table to the dev, you can instead give them views.

Imagine the following scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP1(
    FIELD_1   INT,
    FIELD_2   VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
);
```

Then you create your view:

```
CREATE VIEW V_TEMP1 AS
SELECT FIELD_1 FROM TEMP1;
```

If you try to insert into this VIEW the statement will fail.